# Connecting HDFS to Eclipse in HDP 2.2

Tags: hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I have installed HPD 2.2 on a Virtual box machine. Eclipse and hadoop eclipse plugin are already installed on Host system. I have mounted guest system root directory ( / ) using SSHFS and can successfully connect to it from the host nautilus.

After installing hadoop eclipse plugin i have changed the perspective to Map/Reduce mode. Also I have configured the hadoop install directory through the mounted guest os filesystem.

I need to configure eclipse to connect to hdfs (DFS location) I need Map/Reduce Master Host and DFS master host Port numbers. Please Reply with port numbers of Map/ Reduce master and dfs master so that my eclipse can browse the DFS filesystem.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: The narrowed question is that which are the port number that has to be entered in eclipse so as it can connect to HDFS filesystem in HDP 2.2 virtual sandbox. I tried 8020 for DFS Master but i can only view files neither download nor upload.